# MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Float64,1} to an object of type SentinelArrays.ChainedVector{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}

Tags: julia

I ran the following loop:

```
for k in N
   Load_dict[k] = fill(0.0,8760)
end
```

and got the error specified in the title.

Type of N is `Array{Symbol,1}`, load_dict[k] is `SentinelArrays.ChainedVector{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}` and `fill(0.0, 8760)` generates arrays of  `Array{Float64,1}`.

Can `Array{Float64,1}` be converted to `SentinelArrays.ChainedVector{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}`? Or is there a way to generate `SentinelArrays.ChainedVector{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}` arrays, directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently an appropriate `convert` method is undefined so you need to use a constructor:

```
Load_dict[k] = ChainedVector([fill(0.0, 8760)])
```

However, it seems that the `eltype` of your `Load_dict` is overly narrow (unless you really know what you are doing and why you need a collection of `ChainedVector`).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm trying to use a package written by others. The source of this data type is CSV.read(). So, I should check CSV documentation to see if I can load data with other types.

Comment: You can. But in general I recommend you to do `CSV.read` into a `DataFrame`. This recommendation is opinionated, but the benefit of `DataFrame` is that it allows you to change the type of column, so you could just write `Load_dataframe[:, k] = fill(0.0, 8760)`.

Comment: I used to code in Matlab and just moved to Julia. I'm trying to get more familiar with the basics. So, I appreciate it if you introduce a reference that explains these aspects of Julia. Also, the method you proposed (using constructor) solved my problem; Many thanks!

Comment: DataFramesMeta.jl should be a good place to start. Especially this tutorial https://juliadata.github.io/DataFramesMeta.jl/stable/dplyr/.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will start with it.